# Can't understand 0 rows being returned in php/mysql

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I was using this method to get row-counts for SELECT statements, but it didn't work correctly for LIMIT statements, so I added code to remove the LIMIT from the sql string, but now it doesn't work at all!

When I started using queries with a `LIMIT X, X` at the end, I had to add the section at the top to strip that part from the query, because this method only returns one column - `count` - but the LIMIT offset would cause it to return nothing.

```
function dbRowsCount($sql, $data) {

    # removes "LIMIT X,X" from query
    $no_limit_sql = $sql;
    $pos = stripos($sql, " LIMIT");
    if ($pos!==false) {
        $no_limit_sql = substr($sql, 0, $pos).";";
        # logErrors("original sql=".$sql);
        # logErrors("pos=".$pos."<br>new sql=".$no_limit_sql);
    }

    # query SELECT COUNT(*) instead of SELECT...
    # returns row-count
    $regex = '/^SELECT\s+(?:ALL\s+|DISTINCT\s+)?(?:.*?)\s+FROM\s+(.*)$/is';     
    if (preg_match($regex, $no_limit_sql, $output) > 0) {
        dbQuery("SELECT COUNT(*) AS count FROM {$output[1]}", $data);
        $result = dbFetch();
        $last_rowcount = (int)$result["count"];
        if ($pos!==false) {
            # logErrors("after regex="."SELECT COUNT(*) AS count FROM {$output[1]}");
            # logErrors("row count=".$last_rowcount);
        }
        return $last_rowcount;
    } else {
        # logErrors("Oops! There was an error:<br>Regex did not match SQL.");
        return -1;
    }
}
```

This put directly into MySQL gives count=8:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS count FROM tbl_product WHERE 1 ORDER BY last_update DESC;
```

The output from the `dbRowsCount($sql, $data)` method shows this query should end up the same:

> original sql=SELECT * FROM tbl_product WHERE 1 ORDER BY last_update DESC LIMIT ?, ?;
>   pos=59
>   new sql=SELECT * FROM tbl_product WHERE 1 ORDER BY last_update DESC;
>   after regex=SELECT COUNT(*) AS count FROM tbl_product WHERE 1 ORDER BY last_update DESC;
>   row count=0

**It was working before**, it was returning `rows=8` without the part I added for removing "LIMIT X,X" from the query, but only when the LIMIT was 0,X. When I tried LIMIT 5,5 it wouldn't fetch the column because of the offset, and now it's returning 0 rows for any values.

I also tried this directly with PDO, it worked correctly for both int and string parameters! But using the PDOStatement->rowCount(). (It's not recommended for SELECT queries, so I used the above dbRowsCount method).

```
function dbDebugTest() {
    global $db;
    # logErrors("Beginning dbDebugTest()");
    $stmt = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM tbl_product WHERE 1 ORDER BY last_update DESC LIMIT ?,?");
    $offset = "5";
    $display = "5";
    $stmt->execute(array($offset,$display));
    # logErrors("dbDebugTest() returned rows: ".$stmt->rowCount());
}
```

What is causing the first method to return 0 rows?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All I can see is that when a `LIMIT` is present you add a semi colon behind the query. Perhaps that's the cause of your problem.

If that's not the problem, assuming `dbQuery` and `dbFetch` are working correctly and didn't change, your table is empty? :)

**OP Answer** I was still forwarding the `$data` array to the query when there are no params anymore (since I removed LIMIT X, X)

Comment: The output shows that it comes out correctly though? `new sql=SELECT * FROM tbl_product WHERE 1 ORDER BY last_update DESC;`

Comment: Right, that works on the MySQL prompt. But it might not work the same in `mysql_query()`

Comment: why shouldn't it? It's a query with no params. And this is PDO not mysql_query.

Comment: Sorry, somehow I assumed you were using something else, mainly because I couldn't see what `dbQuery()` does. But have you tried removing the semi-colon though?

Comment: That semi-colon is harmless. In fact I started without it, and out of confusion I had to add it because I don't know what has gone wrong.

Comment: nvm I worked it out. I'm still forwarding the $data array to the query when there are no params anymore (since I removed LIMIT X, X). I don't know why this gave me no PDOExceptions, but I didn't get any. fyi, dbQuery is a simple wrapper for $query->execute() | $query->execute($data), dbFetch is also a wrapper for $query->fetch()

Comment: Okay, that was impossible to figure out from the code presented :) please add your own answer and accept it, I'll get rid of mine.